Is it OK to ask for program/software recommendations here?
Is it within scope of this site to ask about recommendations for crypto software, or is this site reserved for more abstract discussions about crypto algorithms or their implementation?
For example: I was thinking of asking about Android Password Managers with Sync and Web UI?

Software recommendations are generally not a good fit for Stack Exchange, though there is a special site for software recommendations.
Here on Crypto SE we try to stay more to the theoretical level of Cryptography (including implementation details, but not actual code).
